# How to multiply Column vector by Row vector in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to multiply every value in a column vector by the same vector but transposed to row. The output should be a multiplication table matrix. [Like the third example in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80AA9.jpg).

[I tried multiplying a column vector by its transposed form but Mathematica only gives me this which is not a Matrix.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeN3I.png)

Comment: Post your code, not links to your code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark You are not being helpful. I tried to post the code but the Mathematica format didn't translate. I decided to post the picture so that people could see the results from Mathematica. If you already so the picture then you could have answered the question instead of criticising the post.

Comment: `Outer[ Times , m , m ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bryan,

You need to use `Dot`, not `Times`. See [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html).

```
m = {{a}, {b}, {c}}
m.Transpose[m]
```

> {{a^2, a b, a c}, {a b, b^2, b c}, {a c, b c, c^2}}

Answer (score 0):

You might inappropriately define row vectors and column vectors. Try this:

```
rowvec={{a,b,c}};
colvec={{d},{e},{f}};
```

Then the command `dot` will give both inner product and outer product correctly.

```
rowvec.colvec
```

> output: {{a d + b e + c f}}

```
colvec.rowvec
```

> output: {{a d, b d, c d}, {a e, b e, c e}, {a f, b f, c f}}